# what does .attr('name',$this.attr('name')) mean?

Tags: jquery

Somebody posted me this code to me with a problem I had:

```
         $('#txtWeight').each( function() {

 var $this = $(this);
 var $weightText = $("<input type='text' class='txtWeightRow' maxlength='5' onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'/>").attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                 .attr('value',$this.val())

$weight.append($weightText).append('%');

});
```

What I want to know is what does `.attr('name',$this.attr('name'))`. Am I not going to be able to call my input to whatever name I want it to. Does this link the "name" with a previous "name"?

Thanks

Comment: I posted whole code in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying a second argument to the `attr` function **sets** the attribute to this value.

So your example is setting the name attribute of all inputs with name `txtWeightRow` to the value of the name attribute of whatever `$this` is.

In order to see what `$this` is you'd have to supply some more context.

Answer (score 1):

`.attr(name,value)` is a setter, `.attr(name)` is a getter.

`.attr(name,.attr(name2))` is setting the attribute `name` to the value of attribute `name2`

Answer (score 0):

It sets the name attribute of the element you just created (the input) to the same value as the name attribute of the $this object (a separate object).